# Using Cell Contents to reference a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, cross-reference

I've created data tables for each combination of Province, Year, Type and  I've named each Table accordingly (ex AB2015P, or NL2012B) and I am trying to come  up with ratios on another sheet using the data in the tables, and I don't want to manually enter each table name.

My ratios tables have Province in column A, Year in column B, and Type in Column C. I wish to do a vlookup that looks up value "work" in the corresponding table to the first three columns, I've tried a concatenate with putting the three columns into a fourth column, D, but I can't get it to be recognized as a table. I've tried these formulas:

```
=Vlookup("work", A2&B2&C2, 2, false) 
=vlookup("work", D2, 2, false)
=VLOOKUP("work","'"&A2&"'"&"'"&B2&"'"&"'"&C2&"'", 3, FALSE)
```

or any additive I could think of, but I can't get excel to recognize it as a table name.

Answer (score 1):

**First thing;**
I am making the assumption you are using `VLOOKUP` wrong. `VLOOKUP` searches the left most column of the `table_array` for the `lookup_value`. In your case, it will not find `"work"` because I am making the assumption it is in the 3rd column of the table.

You have two options.

1. Move the `Type` column all the way to the left
2. Use [`MATCH/INDEX`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214142/how-to-use-the-index-and-match-worksheet-functions-with-multiple-crite) instead of `VLOOKUP`

**Second thing;** while typing the formula, if you start typing the table name it should popup in a context menu to select. It will look like this;

```
=VLOOKUP("work", AB2015P, 2,FALSE)
```

Comment: BTW, @Charlie, no offense meant, but I didn't glean from his question that "work" was in the third column, or anywhere for that matter.  I just assumed he knows how to use VLOOKUP and is having problems assembling the table names and getting Excel to know what he wants to do.  A constant struggle for us all. :-)

Comment: It would have been clearer if he had said it this way: "I wish to do a vlookup that looks up the value "work" in the *tablename* corresponding to the first three columns" ... of the ratios table.

Comment: @Bandersnatch Thanks, for your input. Yes, it would be nice to know for sure, but we don't. By process of deduction, "province" and "year" are not likely to be the word "work". So, I made the assumption "work" is a "type". It is obvious the OP does not know how to use the `VLOOKUP` function because of the improper syntax. `VLOOKUP` does not have the ability to parse values that have been combined into a single value. `VLOOKUP` searches a range of cells. Unless the `lookup_value` matches the combined values, it won't function.

Comment: Hi @Charlie, I see where you're coming from. I assumed there was one table to hold the 3 parts of the table names (the ratios table) that will also hold calculations using the vlookup, and many other data tables (the named tables) to be used in the vlookup.  But maybe you're right.  In any case, its been a pleasure speaking with you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [INDIRECT()](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/indirect.php)

```
=VLOOKUP("work",INDIRECT(A2&B2&C2),2,FALSE)
```

The [INDIRECT()](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/indirect.php) function converts a text string into a cell or range reference.

I would have tried concatenating the 3 portions of the table reference too, and it seems like that *ought* to have worked, but in this case Excel interprets it as text, which isn't allowed in that position of the VLOOKUP() function.  The same thing would happen if you entered the actual table name in quotes, i.e. "AB2015P".

So using the [INDIRECT()](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/indirect.php) function here converts the text string into an actual range reference.

[Here](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html) is some further information about INDIRECT(), and this website is also a valuable general resource for Excel tips and techniques.

Comment: You might add some referent for learning it you could to make this a better answer so someone can actually learn something as well.

Comment: FYI... I meant reference and +1 for a different solution.